# Azure Function - What Happens to Processed Messages without Outputting Result?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I've written an Azure function and connected it to an IoT Hub's messaging endpoint to trigger the function for all incoming messages. The purpose of the function is to Decompress messages that were previously Compressed using GZIP prior to cellular transmission.

Currently we have the Devices transmitting to the cloud Uncompressed and we're looking to add compression to cut down on transmission costs. We're also currently using Stream Analytics to analyze the messages as they are in the Stream and output them to various hubs, blobs, tables, etc. So once the messages are compressed we will no longer be able to use the Stream Analytics for direction based on message values.

I've developed my Function to decompress the message and output the Result to an Event Hub for further processing.

**My question is:** If I don't output the content will the modified Message live in the queue until it is ingested by another application? Or will my changes disappear if I don't output the Result. And if the uncompressed message is able to live in the queue then will I still be able to use Stream Analytics as I currently have it configured to function.

Comment: I don't exactly know how it works with Events hubs, but with Azure queue it works like this: it tries to process the message, if the function doesn't error out the message is deleted, if the function errors out it will retry up to 5 times and them move the message to poison queue

Comment: IoT Hub messages shouldn't vanish from there, similar to Event Hubs. They should stay in their partitions until retention time is reached.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are asking if Event Hub (the one you are pushing uncompressed messages to) will keep messages if they are not consumed straight away. The answer is yes. Event Hub has a retention policy that you can configure in the Azure portal. Furthermore you can look at the [Event Hub archiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-archive-overview) feature which allows to automatically push the messages to a blob storage. Once your uncompressed messages are in the event hub, then you can still use Stream Analytics as you used to for your processing.

You might also want to look into [Azure IoT Hub routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints#custom-endpoints) which uses messages properties to send them to different custom enpoints without having to crack open the body of the message. That would allow you to do routing without having to decompress messages (if your scenarios allows for using the message properties)

Comment: So if I receive the message in a Function and then decompress the message and then finish execution it should stay uncompressed and then the stream will handle outputting the content to their various locations?